# What is list.count(x => x * x > 1) doing?

Tags: scala

What exactly is the last line doing?

```
val list = List(-1,0,2,3,5)
list.count(x => x * x > 1)
```

The result is 3.

Comment: Have you looked at the API documentation for [count](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#count(p:A=>Boolean):Int)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What exactly is the last line doing?

It is counting the number of elements in the collection that yield true for the predicate `x * x > 1`. The elements are 2, 3 and 5, hence the result is 3.

Answer (score 1):

count() takes predicate. The elements for which predicate returns true will be counted so here you're simple counting elements for which

```
n * n > 1
```

Your list contains: -1,0,2,3,5

```
-1 * -1 = 1
0 * 0 = 0
2 * 2 = 4 > 1
3 * 3 = 9 > 1
5 * 5 = 25 > 1
```

And this is why the result is 3 :)